# Safely transport strings with special characters

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

I have the following source file: https://www.post24.lv/public/files/Pakomatu%20adreses_web_lv.csv

It's a list of addresses with lots of special characters (it's Latvian). I'm having lots of issues with this because the addresses get stored to a different file and then a database, so there's lots of transporting going on and the encoding seems to break somewhere.

Is there a way in PHP that I can safely convert it to HTML entities so that it wouldn't break? I already tried doing `htmlentities($string)` but it gives the wrong entities for some chars.

For example, the 3rd line should start with `Anniņmuižas RIMI pakomāts`, but `htmlentities($string, null, 'cp1252')` converts it to `Anni&ograve;mui&thorn;as RIMI pakom&acirc;ts` which results in `Anniòmuiþas RIMI pakomâts`.

Comment: It's actually as simple as just handling encodings correctly. Do you have any idea about encodings? Do you know what encoding that file is in? Encoding everything to HTML is not fundamentally solving that problem, it's just shifting it around.

Comment: @deceze - yes, i understand the basics of encoding. And yes, it is surely an encoding issue. I just don't want to deal with converting between different encodings everywhere.

Comment: Converting everywhere is indeed madness. You typically convert to one unified encoding like UTF-8 as early as possible and then just make sure your entire workflow uses UTF-8 correctly. If you need to convert back to cp1252 or another encoding somewhere, you do this only on output.